# How to set chroot jail for sshd service properly?

Tags: ssh, jail

on the server side on my debian8,the commands were run :

```
adduser --home /home/user1 user1
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Match User user1
ChrootDirectory /home/user1   #two lines were  added

service sshd restart
```

On the  client side ,

```
ssh user@192.168.1.105
user@192.168.1.105's password: 
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Why can't set chroot jail on the /home/user1  ?

Comment: Did `sshd` log any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably happening is that `sshd` issues the `chroot()` system call, but then when the system tries to start your shell (which is probably something like `/bin/bash`), it doesn't exist...because you've chrooted, so there is no `/bin` directory.

You can copy your shell into `/home/user1/bin/bash`, but you would also need to copy in any required shared libraries.  You can get this by running `ldd /bin/bash`:

```
# ldd /bin/bash
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc3eff5000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f21ceb47000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f21ce943000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f21ce586000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f21ced71000)
```

You could copy each of *these* into the appropriate place in your `chroot` environment, but if you wanted to run any other command, you would need to repeat the above process.

And you may find that some libraries are loaded dynamically, and you would need to copy these as well.

And any required configuration files from `/etc`.  And possibly some device nodes from `/dev`. Etc.

In other words, it's not really worth the effort unless your goal really is to limit access to a single command.